# python not removing punctuation

Tags: python-3.x, file, text, punctuation, txt2tags

i have a text file i want to remove punctuation and save it as a new file but it is not removing anything any idea why?

code:

```
def punctuation(string):
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''

    for x in string.lower():
        if x in punctuations:
            string = string.replace(x, "")

            # Print string without punctuation
    print(string)


file = open('ir500.txt', 'r+')
file_no_punc = (file.read())

punctuation(l)

with open('ir500_no_punc.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(file_no_punc)
```

removing any punctuation why?

Comment: you re-assign the string; you do not change the original instance (you can't: strings are immutable). did you mean to return the changed string? also have a look at [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate).

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, please accept tone by clicking the tick next to it. Doing so will help future readers of this question, just as you have been helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def punctuation(string):
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''

    for x in string.lower():
        if x in punctuations:
            string = string.replace(x, "")

    # return string without punctuation
    return string



file = open('ir500.txt', 'r+')
file_no_punc = (file.read())

file_no_punc = punctuation(file_no_punc)

with open('ir500_no_punc.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(file_no_punc)
```

Explanation:

I changed only `punctuation(l)` to `file_no_punc = punctuation(file_no_punc)` and `print(string)` to `return string`

1) what is `l` in `punctuation(l)` ?
2) you are calling `punctuation()` - which works correctly - but do not use its return value
3) because it is not currently returning a value, just printing it ;-)

Please note that I made only the minimal change to make it work. You might want to post it to our [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, to see how it could be improved.

Also, I would recommend that you get a good IDE. In my opinion, you cannot beat [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) community edition. Learn how to use the debugger; it is your best friend. Set breakpoints, run the code; it will stop when it hits a breakpoint; you can then examine the values of your variables.

Comment: Lolx! How embarrassing. Corrected, and thanks (+1) Btw, love your handle; great book !

Answer (score 0):

taking out the file reading/writing, you could to remove the punctuation from a string like this:

```
table = str.maketrans("", "", r"!()-[]{};:'\"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~")

# # or maybe even better
# import string
# table = str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)

file_with_punc = r"abc!()-[]{};:'\"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~def"
file_no_punc = file_with_punc.lower().translate(table)
# abcdef
```

where i use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate).

note that python strings are immutable. there is no way to change a given string; every operation you perform on a string will return a new instance.